# mail after update query

Tags: php, sql

I want to mail the user after successful update using POST method. the update 
 query works fine but the mail is not sent.

when POST status is 100 or 2, i only end up with the update query being successful but all the code after the update does not work.

```
require_once('db.php');

$status = intval($_POST['status']); 

    if ($status >= 100 || $status == 2) { 
   $qu = "UPDATE tableName SET status = 'Processed' WHERE txn_id = '$txn_id'";

   $re = mysqli_query($conn, $qu);

   if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) == 1){

        require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->setFrom('info@domain.com', 'Example');
        $mail->addAddress('arkinso32@gmail.com');
        $mail->Subject  = 'Mail Subject';
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body     = '


        //message body here
        ';

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'not sent';
        } 
        else {
            echo "*OK*";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing the 'not sent' or 'ok' ?

Comment: "does not work" _how_?  What _is_ happening?

Comment: Do you have a MailServer configured on your system.

Comment: All  email on other pages works fine. Just this one. And not just the mail does not function but all the code within the affected rows does not work. But the update works .    and its a call back page so I don't see the not sent and OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page was a call back url therefore could not view the error message. So i tried a direct $_POST method from my end directly and i noticed the error

I had a mail function above this code where `require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';` was already declared. So it generated an error